# I'm getting this error 500 on my command prompt when trying to add a page to my project

Tags: node.js, express

So i'm trying to set this addpost page and i keep getting this "GET /posts/add 500 4.339 ms - 204" on my command prompt.

full code: https://github.com/vnkvp/blog

thanks for any feedback

**this is my router/posts.js:**

```
router.get('/add', (req, res, next)=>{
    res.render('addpost', {
        'title':'Add post'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**and this is my app.js:**

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());    
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));    
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  req.db = db;
  next();
  });    
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/posts', postsRouter);
```

//catch 404 and forward to error handler

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});
//error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
// set locals, only providing error in development
res.locals.message = err.message;
res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
//render the error page
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**addpost.ejs file**

```
<html>    
<body>   
    <div class="container">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <ul class="errors">
            <% if(errors) { %>
            <% for (var i = 0; i < errors.length;i++) { %>
            <li><%= errors[i].msg %></li>
            <% } %>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
        <form method="POST" action="/posts/add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form">
                <label>Title:</label>
                <input type="text" name="title">
            </div>
            <div class="form">
                <label>Category</label>
                <input type="text" name="title">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That could be a normal info message. Is there something that's not working the way you want it to?

Comment: Oh i see. But the thing is that when i try to access "http://localhost:3000/posts/add" the error message appears and my page doesn't render as it should.

Comment: Please add the file 'addpost.ejs' to your question

Comment: Also looks like you're not adding the ejs middleware to the express app. You might need something like this in your app.js: app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

Comment: I have the middleware included, I just took out some code so it could fit the post. Also included addpost.ejs to the question. My home page renders normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your call to `res.render`

```
res.render('addpost', {
        'title':'Add post'
    });
```

you are sending the variable `title` to your addpost.ejs view, but `title` is not used in that view. That view is trying to use an array called `errors`, but you haven't passed that array to the view so the following will fail:

```
<% if(errors) { %>
            <% for (var i = 0; i < errors.length;i++) { %>
            <li><%= errors[i].msg %></li>
            <% } %>
            <% } %>
```

Try something like this:

```
res.render('addpost', {
        'title':'Add post',
        'errors': ['test error1', 'test error2']
    });
```

If you can see those test errors on your page then you just need to make sure you send the correct error to your view.